# How Long: Converting HTML to Joomla pages

Tags: joomla

I would really appreciate your help with finding out how long it takes a 1-3 year experenced programmer to convert a few HTML pages into joomla 1.5 dynamic pages. I know that some of it depends on how complex the pages are but i'm talking about average pages. That's my first question, my other question is how long will it take a 1-3 year experenced programmer to install all of these componants: Video module, photo gallery module, vertuemart shopping cart. I pay programmers to do this work but i have to make as sure as i can that i'm not over paying them. Thanks in advance for answering these two questions...George

Comment: I think you'll need to specify what you mean by convert a few HTML pages to J1.5 dynamic pages? Do you mean create a new article for each page, or will each page need to be some kind of Joomla plugin or extension?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on complexity and quality of html/css design. Usually 1+ hours, if you want additional modules styled( K2, etc..) you need to add extra time, if style is different for every page, than it take more, plus configuration. Basically conversion is not that difficult, just replace main text with content and add some blocks/regions. I would say average about 8 hours

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it depends... there's not really anywhere near enough info to give even a rough estimate.

Is Joomla already installed? If it is installed and the desired template is in place, then cutting-and-pasting some page content can take a few minutes if it's just text. If not, allow 2-3 hours for basic installation, including debugging and testing of the standard components like sending email. Then another 1-2 hours for basic installation of components. Testing, debugging and setup of Virtuemart can take a *lot* longer, depending on what options for shipping and payments you want.

If you're using a good pre-built template that you're 100% happy with then there should be little to do there, but just positioning and adding discovering what menus work best in which module positions can take a lot of time. Often there is no support in a template for particular components so further styling for the additions is required. Purchased templates vary wildly in quality, some are just not worth the effort, and sometimes template developers take quick-and-dirty shortcuts to get components to look good in their demo, but can take hours to sort out to be useful for anything else.

If you want the Joomla site to look like your old site, or have a custom template built, or radically convert an existing template it can take the length of a piece of string. (One of my clients will easily spend 20 hours endlessly asking me to slightly change spacing, fonts, and colors after signing off on a design and promising that he wouldn't make any more changes. I guess because he can't visualize how things look until he sees the completed site.)

There are plenty of good photo galleries that are bug-free. That shouldn't take long, especially if it comes with a template you already like.

So you may be wondering why all the estimates above vary so much. It just depends on what you've got and what you are really looking for, and what experience the "programmer" has, if it is even in Joomla, or some other CMS, or PHP, or whatever.

Step one in a project like this is to find a programmer you trust not to rip you off; get reliable references if it's someone new. Then get as good an estimate from him or her as he can give, bearing in mind he might have no experience of how you work or how detailed you've been in laying out the plan. Getting an estimate from someone else is not worth much. Then get progress reports as you go along to see where the hours are going so you can judge how to proceed cost-effectively.

Answer (score 0):

is hard to answer at your Q's, the info providet by you is insuficient to make an estimation.
You didn't mentioned anything about customization, complexity of functionalities, integration of those component. Also the time frame depend on the programmer experience and knowledge in Joomla! not just Html knowledge.

Usually, to install some component is easy, lets say for the components you mentioned  i need something like 6-8 h, but this is just the installation process. From here to a good joomla! website is a long way. The more time consuming is the customization and integration of all the functionalities, and this depend on clients requests.
You mentioned Virtuemart, this also can be a bottle neck, Virtuemart installation depend on the shop categories and products no., shipping integration, payment method, images processing,

Other Issue can be the template integration, for a good website is better to have the same look on all the components, VM, Photo gallery etc Your template is acquired one or is a custom development?

But to answer at your Q 1, 
1) 5 to 10 pages should take 2-4h (text edit, custom typography) 
2) 40 to 80h for Video module, photo gallery module, Virtuemart shopping chart

Keep in mind that is just a rough estimation.

Roland

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should take no more than 2-3 hours with minimal configuration included. The only thing that would need more time than this is the video component. Configuration of these components should make the time vary.